# SQL execution failed: operator does not exist: bigint >= timestamp without time zone

Tags: sql, postgres-9.6

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        username TEXT NOT NULL,
        email TEXT NULL,
        created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    
    );
    
    SELECT username, email FROM employee where created_on between '2012-01-20' and '2012-04-24'
```

Comment: This question doesn’t relate to Scala, please remove the tag, or update the question and provide some extra detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That actually seems to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ef8e85/1

Mind though that you have a syntax error in your `CREATE TABLE`, you need to remove the last comma.